# Qt, keep GUI resposive after database call

Tags: qt, qtconcurrent

Let's say when user clicks a button an (slow) operation is performed involving database access. The problem is that the GUI becomes unresponsive if I call the operation directly.

```
ui->comboBox->addItems(obj->getThingsFromDatabase())
```

I've also tried with signals/slots, emit a request to obj and then wait his response (another signal). Anyway, the result was the same, unresponsive GUI.

What should be the approach for this issue?

Comment: please read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html

Comment: And also read up on MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to deal with it is to use another thread for getting things from database.

Here is really good guide how to use threads in Qt:
[threading basics in Qt4](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html)